# How to copy a file from Unix directory to a Windows directory using Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, unix, directory, copy

I'm new to Perl and trying to copy a CSV file from UNIX directory to a Windows shared drive, without using FTP.

Below is my code, in which the source is a CSV file in UNIX directory, whilst `"C:/New folder"` has been created to receive the file. I put the new folder here as a placeholder as I haven't figured out which shared drive should be used.

```
use File::Copy;

sub TestCopyFile
{
    my $source = "/home/user/somefolder/somefile.csv";
    my $target = "C:/New folder";

    copy($source, $target);
}
```

So when I tried to run this from PuTTY, I've been told it is successful. However, I couldn't find the file in the target folder.

Is there anything wrong with my code? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: We need a lot more information in order to be very much help here. you can't just copy a file from a Unix directory to a Windows directory without there being some kind of networking between the two systems. We'd need details of that. If the Windows shared drive is available to the Unix system, then Unix will see the drive with a Unix-style path. What is that? Oh, and which system does this code run on?

Comment: @DaveCross Hi Dave, sorry for the missing links. I'm new to Unix and Perl so not sure what kind of information would be useful. Let me try to implement them.

Comment: Oh, one other thing. And this might just be that you're not showing us all of your code. In the code we see, you define a subroutine called `TestCopyFile()` but you never call that subroutine. So when you say your program runs successfully, that might well be because your program doesn't do anything. It loads a module, defines a subroutine and then exits without running the subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

Not a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) question, really. Windows shared drive means [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block). You need to install [samba](/questions/tagged/samba) and [mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_%28Unix%29) the shared drive into your local file system tree.

Example: `mount.cifs //the-workstation/the-share ~/mnt/the-workstation/the-share -o rw,vers=3.0,sec=ntlmssp,credentials=$HOME/.smbcredentials,cache=strict,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=100,forcegid,addr=172.xxx.xxx.xxx,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,nounix,serverino,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,actimeo=1`

If that's too difficult to figure out in the beginning, you can browse the network with [smb4k](https://kde.org/applications/utilities/smb4k/). Once you have found the correct share, it will tell you the appropriate command for mounting.